# Compiling 64bit MathLink code under cygwin on Windows 7

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, windows

I am aware that building MathLink executables is not without its challenges.

However, I am trying to compile the MathLink example 'addtwo' from a makefile within cygwin on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

I'm using cycgwin as I already have a substantial codebase built in this environment, and I have tried the following compilers:

1. The default gcc compiler. This would not compile, as the -mno-cygwin
   flag has been removed.
2. i686-w64-mingw32-gcc. This compiles but generates undefined
   references for the MathLink functions.
3. x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc. This appears to compile and link correctly.

In all three cases the command line flags to the compiler are the same for compile and link:

```
${CC} -c -mno-cygwin -mwin32 -I${INCS} $<
${CC} -I${INCS} addtwo.o addtwotm.o -L${LIBS} -lML64i3m -mwindows -o $@
```

Although the third configuration compiles and links, it won't run correctly. When the prebuilt addtwo.exe is run from the command line, it puts up a dialogue box requesting the link parameters as expected. Mine will very briefly put up a dialogue box that is minimised, and then exit. Unfortunately gdb does not recognise the file format of the
executable built with x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.

Any insights will reduce hair loss, and I can supply whatever additional information is relevant.

Comment: I suppose the first two cases are working (or rather not working) as expected. Regarding the third, how did you get `libML64i3m.a`? MinGW-w64's `ld` can't link against MS-COFF import libraries as far as I know so you have to create your own from the associated .dll using `gendef` and `dlltool`.

Comment: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc seems to be referencing the import library, as there are no error messages at link time. I wasn't aware of the COFF format issue, so I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Wait... are you linking to the Cygwin import library in `SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Windows/CompilerAdditions/cygwin/lib`? This is in GNU-COFF format, but is for the 32-bit MathLink library (because Cygwin is a 32-bit environment). If it links at all, it certainly won't work correctly at run time since a 64-bit program can't load a 32-bit .dll.

Comment: It's ml64i3m.lib in SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions\mldev64\lib (Mathematica 9.0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you create a file addtwo.tm :

```c
:Begin:
:Function:       addtwo
:Pattern:        AddTwo[i_Integer, j_Integer]
:Arguments:      { i, j }
:ArgumentTypes:  { Integer, Integer }
:ReturnType:     Integer

:End:

:Evaluate: AddTwo::usage = "AddTwo[x, y] gives the sum of two machine integers x and y."

int addtwo( int i, int j)
{
    return i+j;
}

int __stdcall WinMain( HINSTANCE hinstCurrent, HINSTANCE hinstPrevious, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
        char  buff[512];
        char FAR * buff_start = buff;
        char FAR * argv[32];
        char FAR * FAR * argv_end = argv + 32;

        if( !MLInitializeIcon( hinstCurrent, nCmdShow)) return 1;
        MLScanString( argv, &argv_end, &lpszCmdLine, &buff_start);
        return MLMain( argv_end - argv, argv);
}
```

Into the same directory you put this   Makefile  :

```
# Makefile for  addtwo under Windows 7 and cygwin

# this works for http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting %20 Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-release/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-cygwin_rubenvb.tar.xz/download
#
# suppose you installed mingw64 (e.g. from the above link) to cygwin's /opt  ( you may need to install 7zip from http://www .7-zip.org/ )
#
# Do this from a "Cygwin Terminal", a bash shell only once:
#  cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Windows-x86-64/SystemAdditions/"
#  /usr/bin/gendef ml64i3.dll
#  /opt/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool.exe --as-flags=--64 -m i386:x86-64 -k --input-def ml64i3.def --output-lib ml64i3n.lib
#  mv  ml64i3n.lib "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Windows-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mldev64/lib"
#
# then
#    
# before running make, do:
# PATH=/opt/mingw64/bin:/opt/mingw64:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Wolfram\ Research/Mathematica/9.0
#
# now, just cd to the directory where this Makefile and addtwo.tm is and run make 


CPP = "/opt/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe"


CADDSDIR = /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Wolfram\ Research/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Windows-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mldev64
INCDIR = ${CADDSDIR}/include
LIBDIR = ${CADDSDIR}/lib
EXTRACFLAGS = "-mwindows"


MPREP = ${CADDSDIR}/bin/mprep.exe
BINARY = addtwo
all : ${BINARY}

addtwo: addtwotm.o
        ${CPP}  ${EXTRACFLAGS} -I${INCDIR} addtwotm.o -L${LIBDIR} -lml64i3n -o $@

.c.o :
        ${CPP} -c -static-libgcc -I${INCDIR} $<

addtwotm.c : addtwo.tm
        ${MPREP} $? -o $@


clean :
        rm *.o *.exe *tm.c
```

and follow the instructions, then it all works on Windows 7 with Mathematica 9:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Credits: Oleksandr's nice post [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Gic6WbpZOBw/zcLN3Fg0YmAJ)

Comment: Maybe it would be good to include a note that some of the spaces have to be changed to tabs in the Makefile (one of make's peculiarities...)

Comment: @RolfMertig. Wow, many thanks for a complete solution. All done and works like a dream. Thanks also to OleksandrR for kicking things off and Szabolcs for pointing out the makefile changes.